# Render Images in document.directory in a markdown file in swift(SwiftyMarkdown)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, markdown, swift5

Am using SwiftyMarkdown framework to render my .md file to have dynamic formatted data in my VC. But i am not able to load images in my document directory referenced in .md file. I can load images if they are available in Bundle.

Any other option or framework to fix this issue? I want to dynamically load images from server and save them documents directory and refer them in .md file which is also saved in same documents directory/folder. So the url of image and .md file is same.

"MyFile.md" in documents directory contains below content

1. Continue your walk, joining up with your original perimeter path of the item. "

In my VC viewdidload, i access the url path and load nsattributed string to my textview using SwiftyMarkdown frmaework

```
    let url = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("MyFile.md")

    if let md = SwiftyMarkdown(url: url) {
        textView.attributedText = md.attributedString()
    }
```

The formatted text is loaded but no image as its not available in my Bundle. But its saved in the same document directory as that of "MyFile.md"

Hope its clear!

Comment: You need to provide some code to show us what you tried.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasOetjen, i have updated my post with the code